# Normalizing the number of Google results by country

Tags: normalization, web-traffic

I'm trying to visualize the importance of certain phrases in  certain countries. The data I collect is the number of results in Google for different terms in different countries. For example, "Little Red Raiding Hood" in the UK compared to Egypt, or something of that sort. Since I will only use English for the search terms (a dozen countries, on the fly searching, no free use of Google translate), I need to normalize the results according to the amount of local English websites.

E.g. if in Egypt I get 10000 results for "American Pie", and for the US I get one million results, but there are about 100000 websites in English in Egypt, I will conclude that "American Pie" is more popular in Egypt than in the US.

I just need some good way to estimate how many English websites there is in each country. Any ideas?
So far I tried to normalize using "the" as a normalizing term, but the results seem distorted.